# MSQL Reject all queries except stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

For security reasons, I am thinking if its possible to organize MSQL server in a way to reject any kind of query from any user except Stored Procedures which already saved and marked as trusted on a server?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Please add a suitable tag (All we have is MSQL in your title, which is ambiguous at best)

Comment: that's right: my answer is for mysql, is that so?

Comment: I've been looking for MSSQL :- )

Comment: @WildGoat - So why accept a MySQL answer then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.myproc TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges